# Log4j2 logging to file and console

Tags: java, log4j2

I use `Log4j2 2.11.1` in my `Java` project to log to console and also to text file. I initialze it as follows:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(readAllLinks.class);
```

I created `resources/log4j2.propertie`s file to set preferences.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
loggers=file
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

`/logs/propertieslogs.log` file is created on filesystem, but it is empty. I tried it with all the log levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With line `rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout`, every logging operation goes to the console appender (and you see it in the standard output).

To log both to the standard output and to file, use

```
rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout,logfile
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.logfile.ref=LOGFILE
```